# folder one level up PHP header redirect

Tags: php, file, url, redirect, header

```
$home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/homepage.php';

header('Location: '.$home_url);
```

I am using this redirect code for redirection from login page to home page

but

1-->directory/includes/code.php

2->directory/homepage.php

how to redirect from 1 to 2

Comment: pathA->directory/includes/code.php   
Then path 2->pathA/../login.php

Comment: sorry , i am redirecting to the home page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$home_url = '../homepage.php';
header('Location: '.$home_url);
```

Comment: i could give the exact path,but how to come out one level from PHP_SELF

Answer (score 1):

You can do relative redirect using:

```
location = '../';     //one level up
location = '/path'; //relative to domain
```

Comment: do i have to add one more variable before $home_url?

Comment: how can i use both the variables , with PHP_SELF?